# Are there any cool weapons that a monk can use while still being considered an unarmed attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, unarmed-combat

So I’m a lvl 20 tiefling monk and I was wondering is there anything that can upgrade my unarmed strike damage.

My DM gave me a "Monk" book, and when I rolled for the reward, I got a natural 20, which granted me the boost from a d10 to a d12.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. What does "coolness" have to do with increased damage? Furthermore, you're already house-ruled into a higher damage die. Are you looking for some sort of weapon that increases the die size, too?

Comment: Did you ask yesterday's question about a [level 20 tiefling monk](/questions/160249/)? If so, it seems you accidentally may have made a duplicate account. One of our mods can help merge your accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Weapons cannot be used for unarmed strikes

As other answers have pointed out, to use a weapon would make your attack no longer an unarmed strike, so to answer your question directly, no, there are no weapons that you could use whilst still being considered an unarmed strike. However, if you're trying to get some extra damage out of your unarmed strikes...

### You could "upgrade" your unarmed strikes with a +1 bonus

In Hoard of the Dragon Queen, there's a magic item that gives +1 to unarmed attack and damage rolls called the "[Insignia of Claws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/insignia-of-claws)". It's not in the free downloadable supplement PDF for Rise of Tiamat, so you'd only be able to see it by buying the Hoard of the Dragon Queen adventure (or the D&D Beyond pack for that adventure).

But even without seeing it, it's at least evidence that there is something official out there that increases attack and damage rolls for unarmed strikes in the same way that a +1 magic weapon does. You could ask your DM about getting hold of, if not that exact item, then at least for the DM to homebrew something similar.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this I will tell my dm and see if he will accept this.

Comment: @Furiousmonk907 Glad this could be of help. For reference, this "Insignia of Claws" is an _uncommon_ magic item, so it shouldn't be to hard for a level 20 character to find.

Comment: Do u know of anything else that can upgrade my unarmed strike damage or is that all u know of.

Comment: @Furiousmonk907 That is all I know of, I'm afraid. There might be something in the new Eberron book or the Ravnica one, but I don't have those books and don't know those worlds, so I believe it's just this one item, the "Insignia of Claws".

Answer (score 6):

### Short answer: No.

There are no weapons that exist in the [Weapons table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#Weapons) of the PHB that a monk can use effectively (i.e. don't have the "two-handed" or "heavy" property) that deal more than d12 damage.

Additionally, the rule for the monk is not reliant on a particular weapon - instead it is reliant on the monk's [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#MartialArts-227) feature (emphasis mine):

> Your **practice of martial arts gives you mastery of combat styles that use unarmed strikes and monk weapons**, which are shortswords and any simple melee weapons that don't have the two-handed or heavy property.
>
> - [...]
> - You can roll a d4 **in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon.**

(This die [increases as you level up](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#TheMonkTable), ultimately leading to a total of a d10 for base damage. It is not the weapon you use that boosts this die increase - it's your skill as a martial artist.)

So, following these rules, what the DM has granted you is effectively some kind of "masterworked" weapon, designed specifically for a master monk to make them even more deadly than any other monks that have come before. Either that or it is magic, and inherently sharpens your senses beyond human perception, making you more precise, and deadly.

What this does allow for, however, is that your Flurry of Blows all deal a base 1d12 damage. This means that, at level 20, when you take the Attack action, you can make two attacks as part of it, and you have the option to use a ki point to make 2 more attacks as a bonus action, all dealing 1d12 damage ( + Dex modifier).

Comment: @Furiousmonk907 if by "abandon" you mean delete, try to avoid that. This question and answer can be useful for others to come, so it can be worthwhile leaving it up

Comment: I mean not responding to stuff if I meant delete I would say delete

Comment: Btw I got a “monk” book, rolled a nat20 for reading it and I got the dmg boost.

Answer (score -1):

There aren't any weapons that let you still be unarmed. But there are "monk weapons". According to the Monk rules most of what works with unarmed can also use monk weapons. [Monk weapons are](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#MartialArts):

> At 1st level, your practice of martial arts gives you mastery of combat styles that use unarmed strikes and monk weapons, which are shortswords and any simple melee weapons that don’t have the two-handed or heavy property.
>
> ...
>
> Certain monasteries use specialized forms of the monk weapons. For example, you might use a club that is two lengths of wood connected by a short chain (called a nunchaku) or a sickle with a shorter, straighter blade (called a kama). Whatever name you use for a monk weapon, you can use the game statistics provided for the weapon in the Weapons section.

Assuming you can use monk weapons, then there are all kinds of cool weapons used by Chinese, Japanese, or even Western monks that could be re-purposed.

There are some class features that seem to be intended only to be used with unarmed strikes, but hopefully you and your DM can sort something out if that's the way you want to play.

Comment: I don't know about your homebrew, but hopefully it follows the way that monk is generally written, so you can use monk weapons.

Comment: Well it’s just that my unarmed strikes went up one better dice so instead of 1d10 dmg. I can do 1d12 dmg.

Comment: But it said that after I attack with a monk weapon or unarmed strike that I can make an UNARMED STRIKE as a bonus action, so I wouldn’t be able to use a weapon to hit or if I used flurry of blows.

Comment: @Furiousmonk907 That's correct. It would be too unbalanced for a monk be able to attack so much with such high die, so the rules are balanced to let the monk attack a lot but not deal as much damage. You can always wield 2 light weapons and then use two weapon fighting to attack as a bonus action. You can also attack with an unarmed strike after attacking with a monk weapon.

Comment: Yes I can do that true but I really want to upgrade my dmg. dice because I don’t have any good weapons.

Comment: And I would only be able to use a short sword which is 1d6 sooooooo that would only be 2d6 dmg. and that’s with two attacks which I can already do because of the extra attack ability. And I could do 1d12 dmg. each attack soooo yeah.

Comment: @Furiousmonk907 I think you should consider just how little effect upgrading damage does. For example going from 1d10 to 1d12 only increases your average damage from 5.5 to 6.5. If you go up to 2d6 damage then that is average of 7. 2d8 is average 9. If you want more damage you should consider boosting dex, lowering enemy AC, adding effects, etc. There are a lot of items you could use to help your damage better than asking for homebrew.

Comment: So your goal is to deal more damage with your unarmed attacks? Not to just find a cool weapon?

Comment: Well I was thinking something like having an item give me a dmg. boost while it still being an unarmed attack so I can use my monk abilities like flurry of blows

Comment: Like having brass knuckles or something but I don’t want my dm thinking that I’m being greedy and just plain out asking for stuff benefitting me

Comment: Insignia of Claws is about the only item that will boost your unarmed attack damage https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/insignia-of-claws

Comment: That just redirected me to a website telling me to buy that weapon not telling me what it is and does

Comment: Do u know of anything better than that or is that it?

Comment: That's all I can think of. There's not a lot for unarmed because you get a lot more attacks than other classes. There are a lot of advantages to monk already :P

Comment: @jgn: I've removed the followup comment containing the link, because it points to a site inappropriate rehosting non-SRD content.